# Is it possible to deploy multiple spring-boot applications in AWS Beanstalk using the same EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, vue.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, microservices

I have an application that is composed of multiple spring boot microservices and a front end application using vue.js, and I want to deploy them in AWS beanstalk to avoid handling infraestructure.

I know how to deploy a single microservice into beanstalk, but I dont want to have as many beanstalk instances as microservices I have, because I don't have the money to pay for many service instances.

So my question is: How to deploy multiple spring boot applications and the vue.js application into only one beanstalk instance?

Thank you.

Comment: Which Beanstalk type are you using?  Tomcat should be able to deploy any number of web applications depending on your configuration though Springboot isn't a web-app per se.

Comment: What about the front end application? do I need to set up a different beanstalk instance? one for the microservices and one for the vue.js, isn't it possible to have them at the same beanstalk instance?

Answer (score 1):

Elastic beanstalk accepts zip files. You can zip 2 or more war files and upload as a zip. Importantly among the zipped files, one has to be the root war, so that base url has one application to point to.

Below documentation should give you more details
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-multiple-war-files.html

Comment: Can you provide any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Is it the same for deployment multiple spring boot  jars?